# Parsing Time from a String in Ruby

Tags: ruby, date

I have some strings which are dates, which I find using regex

```
d = myData.scan(/....\d*..\d{4}/)
```

Which yeilds, for example, "Jun 15, 2013," though these dates change across instances. I would like to parse these and convert them from month abbreviation to full month.

This works (requiring 'time'):

```
Time.parse("Jun 15, 2013").strftime("%B %d, %Y")
=> "June 15, 2013"
```

But this doesn't:

```
Time.parse("d").strftime("%B %d, %Y")
```

Like I said, the actual dates change, and I'm trying to automate this with a script. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

UPDATE: Sorry—I was just skipping a step, I think. I thought I already tried this, but I guess not. This works:

```
d = myData.scan(/....\d*..\d{4}/)
d2 = Time.parse("d")
date = Time.parse("d2").strftime("%B %d, %Y")
```

Comment: Does your actual source code pass a string to `Time.parse` (`parse("d")`), or are you using the variable?

Comment: We know the code can't pass `"d"` to `parse` because Ruby doesn't allow that. `Time.parse('d')` returns 
`ArgumentError: no time information in "d"`. As a result, none of the code using `parse("d")` or `parse("d2")` could possibly work, in spite of what the OP says.

Answer (score 2):

Putting your variable names in quotes doesn't work. So instead of:

```
Time.parse("d")
```

you have to use:

```
Time.parse(d)
```

Furthermore `scan` returns an array.

```
"Jun 15, 2013".scan(/....\d*..\d{4}/)     #=> ["Jun 15, 2013"]
```

append `[0]` to get the array's first element:

```
"Jun 15, 2013".scan(/....\d*..\d{4}/)[0]  #=> "Jun 15, 2013"
```

Complete example:

```
my_data = "Jun 15, 2013"
d = my_data.scan(/....\d*..\d{4}/)[0]
date = Time.parse(d).strftime("%B %d, %Y")
#=> "June 15, 2013"
```

Answer (score 1):

From what @craigeley mentioned, if `d` is your data:

```
Time.parse(d).strftime("%B %d, %Y")
```

Comment: `scan` returns an array, so `d[0]` should work

Comment: How the heck `#parse` is not even once mentioned in `Time` [API docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Time.html)!? How is one expected to learn about that method existence?

Comment: It's in the Standard Library http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.4/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html